# iOS app crashes at launch with `DYLD 1 Library missing`

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, dyld, rpath

I have 2 machines where I am exporting an IPA from my xcarchive. In the machine `A` it's working. I have no problems and I can install the app and use it. But when exporting it from the machine `B` I have a crash at the launch:

```
Termination Reason: DYLD 1 Library missing
Library not loaded: /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dnlmptwccpzuvfamalwjuzqgqqjc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/mylib.dylib
Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/6AAE33-320-403-BDA-21C117699/MyApp.app/MyApp
Reason: tried: '/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dnlmptwccpzuvfamalwjuzqgqqjc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/mylib.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/mylib.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/mylib.dylib' (no such file)
```

It's clear that the linking is wrong. It's the same project/configuration and the same Xcode version in both machines.

It is added in the "Embed Libraries" and "Runpath Search Paths" is set to `@executable_path/Frameworks`

Indeed, the archives are different. The archive that work has a folder `@rpath` for the dynamic library. On the other hand, the archive that crashes has a folder `Users`

Working:
[image]

Crashing:
[image]

Any ideas?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the cmake version on the machine with the problem. Updating to 3.23 solved my problem. Indeed it seems to be a bug on cmake 3.15

https://github.com/libevent/libevent/issues/920